# How can I dynamically add file inputs in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create an image upload container where I can dynamically add file inputs.

I'm trying to achieve this

[image: Image container example]

My current code isn't working as it appears I can't repopulate file inputs if my local state changes. I'm also trying to use a controlled workflow with this which is proving to be difficult for me. Can anyone point me in the right direction

My current code looks like this

```
renderImageInputs = () => {
    const { images } = this.state;
    const imageInputs = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
        imageInputs.push(
            <Image value={images[i].file} imageId={`image-${i}`} image={images[i].preview} onImageChange={(e) => this.onImageClicked(e, i)}/>
        )
    }

    imageInputs.push(
        //push empty image input here
    )

    return imageInputs;
}
```

Comment: Post your code please